# Michelson interferometer but with 1 arm

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

If we design a setup similar to Michelson Interferometer but with one mirror only. So, there is an angle between the 2 rays to the detector. Will we get an interference pattern on the screen?

[image]

Comment: For your set up the path difference is of the order of 2 metres. A multi mode helium-neon (HeNe) laser typically has a coherence length of about 20cm whereas for a single mode HeNe laser the coherence length can exceed 100 m. A standard laser diode usually has a coherence length of less than a millimeter and an ordinary light emitting diode (LED) has a coherence length on the order of microns.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is located in the location indicated by the "Detector" in your diagram, and the coherence length of the laser is greater than the path difference between the two beams, then yes, you will see an interference pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just wondering if you have a reference/ paper for similar above setup tested experimentally with one arm?

Comment: @WaelKhatib, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to study the total destructive interference with the above setup. I'm trying to examine whether the photons will scatter around the dark spot (total destructive interference).

Comment: @WaelKhatib, I don't know if this arrangement has a name, but you could look at the [Rayleigh interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_interferometer) for a system that similarly keeps the two beams near-coincident.

Comment: Thank you @The Photon. Do you know a Lab can test this setup for me? Thanks again.